# How to get the char count between two indexes in a string?

Tags: c#, string, indexing

```
private IEnumerable<Player> GetGamePlayers(string content, string map)
{
    List<Player> Players = new List<Player>();

    var positions = new List<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        positions.Add(content.IndexOf(String.Format("[{0}] (com.riotgames.platform.gameclient.domain::PlayerParticipantStatsSummary)", i)));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        positions.Add(content.IndexOf(String.Format("[{0}] (com.riotgames.platform.gameclient.domain::PlayerParticipantStatsSummary)", i), positions[4] + 500));
    }

    foreach (var position in positions)
    {
        //NEED HELP HERE!
        var section = content.Substring(position, )
        Players.Add(ParsePlayer(section));
    }

    return Players;
}
```

The positions variable holds the start indexes of the sections I need.

So basically, I need a substring from position[0] to position[1] - 1.

Any suggestions?

Comment: From your code it's not clear what you're trying to do, but you can just subtract the indexes to get the number of characters between them!

Comment: Oh you can do that? So: var count = position[1] - position[0];?

Comment: Depending on your definition of "between" you might need to add or subtract 1. And of course it depends on how you define a char. Since in UTF-16 one codepoint doesn't always correspond to a `System.Char`. And a unicode-codepoint doesn't always correspond to a single rendered symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you use a regular for loop since you need the index:

```
for (int i = 0; i < positions.Count-1; i++)
{
        string section = content.Substring(positions[i], 
                                           positions[i+1]-positions[i]);
        Players.Add(ParsePlayer(section));
}
```